# Dynamic meta description and keywords - Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that creates a dynamic page title in a Wordpress template page:

```
$prodname = sanitize_text_field($_GET['prod_name']);

$prodname = esc_sql( $prodname );

global $wpdb;
$products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM product_data WHERE prod_name='$prodname';");

add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');

function assignPageTitle() {

    global $products;

    foreach($products as $product){

        echo "".$product->prod_page_title."";

    }

}
```

I would like to use a similar technique to do meta description and meta keywords too, but i'm not sure what the Wordpress hooks are for those two. Anyone able to help?

**UPDATE:**

This code works to add meta description and meta keywords just before the closing `</head>` tag

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'assignMetaInfo' );

function assignMetaInfo() {

    global $products;

    foreach($products as $product){

        echo "<meta name='description' content='Test Description' />";

        echo "<meta name='keywords' content='Test Keywords' />";

    }

}
```

Comment: are you using any SEO plugin?

Comment: I'm using Genesis framework running a custom child theme. Genesis has it's own SEO settings, but as these template pages are dynamic using data from a MySQL database, I can't really use it, likewise with other plugins like Yoast. Unless you know of a method to add dynamic content via a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'assignMetaInfo' );

function assignMetaInfo() {

    global $products;

    foreach($products as $product){

        echo "<meta name='description' content='Test Description' />";

        echo "<meta name='keywords' content='Test Keywords' />";

    }

}
```

Comment: yes that how you have to do it, coz if you don't use any seo plugin then WP by default does not create this `meta`. but you should have only one `meta desc` and `keyword` per page not more then that. for loop may generate more then 1 if products has more then 1 data.